# Google Drive API > Golang > quickstart : Cannot progress after "{App} wants access to your Google Account" step

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

From the website (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/go) I found quickstart go sample code and guides for what to do. I've done everything but I am not sure that everything was completed well.
(1) Made a new project at Google Cloud
(2) Enabled Google Drive API
(3) Done setting OAuth consent screen as what the guide says so
(4) Made OAuth 2.0 ID
(5) Downloaded 'credential json'
(6) run the sample code quickstart go
(7) It was successful to read credential json and got a link for signing in with google account and
generating (or receiving) token

However at this step 7 I've got some problem.
When I open this given link at Chrome (or Firefox),
Choose an account > Google hasn't verified this app > now expected to see "Advanced" option but I only see "Continue" and "Back to safety". > so my option is click "Continue" > {App} wants access to your Google Account > Click "Continue" > web page redirect to localhost page as already defined in credentials json file and nothing happens any more. Even no return values for the running quickstart go code.

Unfortunately I've figured out google had an update regarding 'Google account sign in page' recently.
May this could be the reason that I cannot find "Advanced" option at my upper description?
Or
My OAuth setting is wrong?

Any one have an experience to give me some help for this?